# kubernetes のチュートリアルで良く出る localhost のIPアドレスはクラウド上だとどうなるか

Tags: kubernetes

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/

クラウド上でkubernetesを構築しているのですが、kubernetesのチュートリアルやQiitaの記事を見ると、サービスに公開した内容を `http://localhost:port` にアクセスすれば、ブラウザアクセスできると書かれているのですが、これはローカル環境にかぎった話になると思われるのですが、クラウドであればどこのIPがlocalhostのIPに代わる所か、調べる方法教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: どんなクラウドサービスをお使いですか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"localhost" は常に自分自身を指す「ループバック・アドレス」です。IPアドレスで表記する場合、一般的には "127.0.0.1" を使用します。

サービスがクラウド上にあっても、対象のサーバから **自分自身に** アクセスする際には localhost が使えます。
一方で、別の端末から (クラウド上の) サービスに接続するのであれば、対象のIPアドレスを指定する必要があるでしょう。

参考:
[ローカル・ループバック・アドレス（127.0.0.1）とは？ - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0610/14/news021.html)